# Correlation between two pandas dataframe columns by passing correlation method

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am using below code to calculate the correlation.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[301.9,305.2,303.3,305.9,304.1,304.4,305.6,303.7,304.4,303.7,303,305.2,303.3,303.7,304.1,303.7,303,301.5],  
                  "B":[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2]}) 
df.corr(method='pearson')
```

Is there any way to pass correlation method as below?

```
val=df['A'].corr(df['B'])
print(val)
```

Basically I need to use some thing like below.

```
print(df['A'].corr(df['B']),'spearman')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas DataFrame.corr can get a method, as explained in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html).

Your code should just work:

```
df['A'].corr(df['B'],'spearman')
```

Or, equivalently (but less efficient):

```
df.corr('spearman').loc['A','B']
```

The only problem with the code in your example was that your parenthesis was a bit off, double-check it.

Comment: Yes, it worked, i was overlooked at the parenthesis.                                                                                     print(df['A'].corr(df['B'],method='spearman'))